Visual Studio Code script to create profile and install specific extensions to that profile in a multi user lab deployment
I see that I can export a profile and extensions to a .code-profile file but there doesn't seem to be a CLI or scripted way of importing this.
We're deploying Visual Studio Code to our labs this summer and the prof wants to have the following already configured for each user as they log in:
1. Keep the "Default" profile as is with no additional extensions except for what comes with VSC
2. Create/Have another profile which will have a handful of additional installed extensions
So via GUI actions importing a .code-profile seems to work to create a profile with specific installed extensions but there doesn't seem to be a way to script this.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/181553
While I can take extensions that have installed in a ~/.vscode folder and them move them to /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions, which makes them available to all profiles, this still doesn't work for the prof since they want to have the Default profile have no other extensions except for the usual ones that come with a standard Visual Studio Code install.
I've read through some of the CLI documentation but it didn't seem like I could accomplish all the prof requirements.

Working with profiles at the command line isn't too difficult:

Create a new profile

% code --profile "Some Course"


Install extensions to that profile

% code --install-extension vscodevim.vim --profile "Some Course"

Now, the course is blessed by Vim and the real editing can begin!
Anything else you want to do that can be done at the command line can be done to a specific --profile, just like that.
